# Remove specific line in text file

Tags: java, file, text, methods, bufferedreader

I have a .txt file, `inventory.txt`. it contains

```
banana, 1, 15
dog, 1, 15
cats, 20, 30
```

I would like to create a method that would delete one of these lines, let's say the `cats` line, by either inputting `cats` or `cats, 20, 30`

My code prompts the user for `removedItem`, reads the `inventory.txt`, trims each line, and checks if `trimmedLine` is equal to `removedItem`, then `continue` and writes to `deleteditems.txt` every `line` read excluding the `trimmedLine`. I then close both `writer` and `reader`, delete the original `inventory.txt`, and rename `deleteditems.txt` to `inventory.txt`. However, it does not do anything, and the line remains after compiling.

**Code:**

```
public void removeItems() throws IOException {

        String line;

        File inventory = new File("src/inventory.txt");
        File temp = new File("src/deleteditems.txt");

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/inventory.txt"));
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("src/deleteditems.txt"));

        displayInventory();

        temp.createNewFile();

        System.out.println("what item do you want to remove");
        String removedLine = scan.next();

        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String trimmedLine = line.trim();
            if(trimmedLine.equals(removedLine)) {
                trimmedLine = "";
            }
            writer.write(line + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
        reader.close(); 
        writer.close(); 
        inventory.delete();
        temp.renameTo(inventory);

    }
```

**Output:**

```
banana, 1, 15
dog, 1, 15
cats, 20, 30
what item do you want to remove
cats, 20, 30
```

**Text file after compiling:**

```
banana, 1, 15
dog, 1, 15
cats, 20, 30
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with what you're doing:

- you are comparing the whole line to the input with "equals" .... for
  that to match, the user couldn't not just enter "cats", they'd need
  to enter "cats, 20, 30" since that is what a line contains.
- even if it did match, you're still writing "line" to the output file

You can fix it like this:

```
 while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String trimmedLine = line.trim();
            if(!trimmedLine.startsWith(removedLine)) {

               writer.write(line + 
                  System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            }
        }
```

This will only write the line if it does not start with the input.

As a side-note, you should look at using the ["try with resources"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement to open your reader/writer to ensure things get cleaned up properly even in the event of an exception.

Comment: still doesn't remove the line using ```startsWith``` nor ```contains``` :\

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to check for an exact match with .equals()

try using .contains(CharSequence)
or .startsWith()

```
        String newInventory = ""; 

        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
           String trimmedLine = line.trim();
           if(!trimmedLine.contains(removedLine)) {
              writer.write(line + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
              continue;
           }

           newInventory += line;
        }

        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputSteam("src/inventory.txt");
        fout.write(newInventory.getBytes());
```

Comment: still doesn't remove the line :\

Comment: if you want to remove data from the file you need to over write. Lemme post an edit on the answer.